# Generate Multiple CHECKBOXES using JHTML - Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, checkbox, joomla

I have this code that generates a SELECT list dropdown.

```
    $query->select('position_id AS value, position_name AS text');
    $query->from('#__football_player_positions');
    $query->order('position_name');

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $options = $db->loadObjectList();

    if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
        JError::raiseWarning(500, $db->getErrorMsg());
    }

    array_unshift($options, JHtml::_('select.option', '', JText::_('-Select Position-')));

    return $options;
```

My question is how can I generate CHECKBOXES with name like fooBar[] so after I can get values of the selected CHECKBOXES

If I `JHtml::_('checkbox.option'` it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Joomla doesn't support multiple list. We have to create that manually

```
$html = '<select id="" name="sth[]" multiple="multiple">';
//here values
$html = '</select';
return $html;
```